# WPF how to set Keyboardinput focus on 2 Canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

So how i have thies Xamarin Code:

```
<Canvas x:Name="player1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="393,232,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="10" KeyDown="keys_KeyDown" Keyboard.GotKeyboardFocus="Players_GotKeyboardFocus">
            <Canvas.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Canvas.Background>
        </Canvas>
    <Canvas x:Name="player2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="978,232,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="10" Keyboard.GotKeyboardFocus="Players_GotKeyboardFocus">
            <Canvas.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF002EFF" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Canvas.Background>
        </Canvas>
```

and thise C#:

```
 private void Players_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Keyboard.Focus(player1);
    }

    private void keys_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var y = Canvas.GetTop(player1);

        if (e.Key == Key.W)
        {
            Canvas.SetTop(player1, y + 5);
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.S)
        {
            Canvas.SetTop(player1, y - 5);
        }
    }
```

I tied but it didnt work so can somebody please help?
It schould be that if you press W player1 schould move a littel up and if you press S down.

Comment: So you have focused the player1 canvas `Keyboard.Focus(player1);` that means this `keys_KeyDown` is also of  player1 canvas ? can you show XAML ?

Comment: Did you set canvas `.Focusable` to `true`?

Answer (score 0):

I add `Focusable="True"` for the canvas **player1** and a `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` to make it focused , the xaml as below shown:

```
<Canvas Background="Azure">
    <Canvas x:Name="player1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="200,100,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="10" Focusable="True" KeyDown="keys_KeyDown" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="player1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
        <Canvas.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Canvas.Background>
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="player1Transform" />
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    </Canvas>
    <Canvas x:Name="player2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="300,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="10"  Focusable="True">
        <Canvas.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF002EFF" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Canvas.Background>
    </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

Then you can use below code to implement the function:

```
private void keys_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.W)
        {
            player1Transform.Y += 5;
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.S)
        {
            player1Transform.Y -= 5;
        }

    }

    private void player1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.player1.Focus();
    }
```